# Can I hide a chart title in Superset?

Tags: css, apache-superset

In the below, I'm trying to hide the text "PV Monocrystalline" to provide a bit more room for the number. If i delete the content it still occupies the space and shows `<empty>` as the title. Is hiding this part of the chart entirely an option?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by editing the CSS of the dashboard the chart is displayed on:

1. Go to your dashboard, and click on Edit Dashboard
2. Click on the dropdown (next to Switch to View Mode), and select "Edit CSS"
3. In the "Live CSS Editor" box; type some CSS that will make the header disappear.

   This should work

   ```
   .chart-header {
       display: none;
   }
   ```
4. Close the popup, and Save Changes

Comment: Thank you, that hides the header by the space doesn't get reassigned so the number stays the same size. I think that's probably an edit to create a custom chart type

Comment: Hiding the header also disables the ability to edit/explore the chart from the dashboard. Removing `subheader_line` would get you some more room but is presumably a global setting. The number itself doesn't occupy the full height of it's container so will explore. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 4):

As of release 1.3.0, you can use this dashboard CSS:

```
.header-title > .editable-title {
  display:none;
}
```

This doesn't necessarily provide more space. But it does hide titles for charts.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Comment: This is hiding header for all the charts. Is there a way to hide it only for a specif chart in a Dashboard?

Comment: @RahulDiggi - see my other answer I just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77585957

Answer (score 1):

You can find and use the chart's specific chartID. See [here](https://preset.io/blog/customizing-superset-dashboards-with-css/#selectingstyling-specific-individual-charts) for more info.

#### Example:

```css
[data-test-chart-id="102"] > div:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

#### Before:

[image]

#### After:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of hiding chart name is to rename it as an empty character. There is the link where you can get one: https://www.editpad.org/tool/invisible-character